# Python JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1

Tags: python, json

I got an error : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). But don't understand why.

Here is my code :

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "apiurl"
data = json.loads(url)

# Open the URL as Browser, not as python urllib
page = urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
infile = urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
data = infile.decode('ISO-8859-1')  # Read the content as string decoded with ISO-8859-1

command_obj = {x['command']: x for x in data}

with open('new_command.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(command_obj, f, indent=2)
```

With this fonction, i'm just trying to fetch data from an api and modify its format. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is your `url` a text representation of a JSON object?

Comment: It's a json object yes! here is the url : https://api.sheety.co/be29a67e-80b2-4f73-ace9-9a0a2f40f4a6

Comment: Is _the URL itself_ (`"https://api.sheety.co/be29a67e-80b2-4f73-ace9-9a0a2f40f4a6"`) a JSON object? `json.loads(url)` will attempt to parse this very string as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the *URL* itself (and not its content) as JSON:

```
data = json.loads(url)
```

... instead you want to read the *content returned from the API* as JSON:

```
# Open the URL as Browser, not as python urllib
page = urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
infile = urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
data = infile.decode('ISO-8859-1')

# avoid re-using `data` variable name
json_data = json.loads(data)
```

However, be aware that JSON should always be returned as UTF-8, never as ISO-8859-1 / latin-1.